# correlate GCP sys- with GCP project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

Is there any way to correlate GCP project IDs to Apps Script project name? Apps scripts create a default GCP project internally. We need to correlate appscripts with the gcp project

Comment: Not that I know of. The default GCP project id is google managed. However, if you have a paid google workspace account with your own domain you can access the ids of those projects from the GCP developer console, But it won't do you much good as google-managed projects are bound by so many constraints you'll be forced to migrate to a standard project anyway

Answer (score -1):

You can check the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) to switch a script's default GCP project to a standard GCP project. If you are using the new editor, please follow the steps below:

1. If you don't have a suitable GCP project, create a new one by following the [Create a project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project) instructions. Set a memorable GCP project name so that you can more easily locate it in the [GCP console Manage Resources](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager) page. This name is also used to identify the script when Apps Script asks users to authorize it.
2. If you want to use an existing GCP project, open the [GCP console Manage Resources](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager) page and locate an existing GCP project to use. You must have resourcemanager.projects.update permissions for the GCP project. You can't use a project that was automatically created by Apps Script.
3. [Determine the Project number of your GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#determining_the_id_and_number_of_a_standard_gcp_project).
4. Open the script whose GCP project you want to replace.
5. At the left, click Project Settings settings.
6. Under Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project, click Change project.
7. Enter the new project number and click Set project.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it talks about how to change a scripts default GCP project. The original question asks how to find the apps script that corresponds to any given project ID.